# DRF error messages combine model and custom field error messages in response

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have this model in django:

```
      product_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, required = True)
      code = models.CharField(max_length = 13, blank = False, required= True)
      product_note = models.CharField(max_length = 2000, blank = True, required=False)
```

There is a custom validator and sanitizor for code which is applied in serializer. Now my issue is if both fields are incorrect (missing product_name and incorrect code), I get reply :"this field is required" for the product name and the code error message is never shown. If product_name is passed according to its model definitions though, the code error message is shown.

Is there a way both the model definition (i.e. required) and custom validation can be processed and returned at once?

```
from products.models import Product
from rest_framework import serializers
from validations.product_validators import valid_product_code

class NewProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, data):
        # validate data here
        err_msg = {}

        code = valid_product_code(data['code'])

        if code == '':
            err_msg['code']=['The entered product do not follow product code rules and could not be sanitized']

        if err_msg:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(err_msg)

        data['code'] = code
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_name', 'code','product_note')
```

Answer (score 0):

if code fields is not empty serializer call validate_code() method.

```
class NewProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_name', 'code','product_note')

    def validate_code(self, value):
        # validate data here
        err_msg = {}

        code = valid_product_code(value)

        if code == '':
            err_msg['code']=['The entered product do not follow product code rules and could not be sanitized']

        if err_msg:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(err_msg)

        return value
```